# Convert ImageView to Bitmap with native resolution

Tags: android, bitmap

I have the following problem: my `imageView` gets converted to a `bitmap`, when saving the bitmap into my gallery I can clearly see that the resolution/format of the bitmap is the same as the imageView one. But i want to get the un-cropped resolution.

**Is it possible to convert the imageView to a Bitmap with the native resolution?**

> I want to convert the imageView to a bitmap and not creating a new Bitmap by the image source (URL) as I would need to implement a new Async...

**Current converting code:**

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
```

**To clearify:**
The image on website has the resolution `800*800px` and my imageView has the resolution `300*300dp` (way smaller) and I want the res of the source..**Is that even possible?**

Comment: What you mean with "native solution"?

Comment: native resolution: e.g image on website has the resolution 500*800 px and my imageView has the res 300*300dp (ways smaller) and I want the res of the source..

Comment: Use glide library to get image as bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Just use Glide to load your image with custom Target.

```
Glide.with(context) //or view
    .asBitmap()
    .load(imagePath)
    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            // do whatever you want with the 'resource' Bitmap
        }
        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle so you can recycle your bitmap
        }
    })
```